# Flourishing as a standard

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Just read that "***Flourishing as a standard***" is not a meaningful expression. However, I've found several usages of the expression in published books.

Any idea on acceptance or rejection of its meaningfulness?

Comment: It could be meaningful, in the right context.  Who said it wasn't?

Comment: May you give an example of  using it in the wrong context?

Comment: Well, "Potato flourishing as a standard truck" would be pretty meaningless.

Comment: Exactly! I thought it should be more complicated.

Comment: HTML5 seems to be flourishing as a standard. Goodbye, flash players!

Comment: Btw, where did you read it "wasn't meaningful"

Comment: "Flourishing as a standard" would be appropriate in a situation where several "standards" were effectively competing.  Let's say the XXX and YYY protocols for Advanced Network Potato Farming both do essentially the same thing (only differently), and XXX is being used a lot while relatively few people use YYY.  So XXX is "flourishing as a standard".

Answer (score 2):

That expression could be considered nonsense because 'standard' means everyone is already using "it" ( the standard ), while 'flourishing' indicates the period of growth before a standard has become, well, standard. :-)

Practically speaking, however, people tend to say 'standard' while really intending to say something like 'proposed standard'.

Comment: Perhaps it means that it is predicted to be a standard after flourishing.

Comment: Agreed, I would take it to mean "the impending or imminent standard-to-be".